# question regarding the joint_state_publisher_gui launch

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros2, urdf

is there a way to start the joint_state_publisher_gui in an already existing launch file? Can't find anything regarding this. Would be amazing if anybody has an idea to share =)

Kind regards

What i've tried so far:
Creating a joint_state_publisher_gui node in a .py launch file; it didn't find a package called joint_state_publisher_gui